# Fizz buzz extended

Tags: python, fizzbuzz

I know how to make a basic fizzbuzz, but now that I am asked to extend it and make it so that the user inputs the number, I cant seem to make it work how the sample code does.

{Game Requirements:
Provide a welcome message,
Ask the user to enter a value,
Check it is correct against the stored value in the sequence,
If the value is correct, it should move on to the next number
If the value is incorrect, then the game should be over}

```
print("Welcome to FizzBuzz.")
print("Enter a number, Fizz, Buzz or FizzBuzz:")
for x in range (1,16):
  answer = input()
  fizz = (x%3 == 0)
  buzz = (x%5 == 0) 
  fizzbuzz = (x%3 and x%5 == 0)
  if answer == x:
    print ("next")
  elif answer == "fizz": 
    print("Next")
  elif answer == "buzz":
    print("Next")
  elif answer == "Fizzbuzz":
    print("next")

  else:
      print("incorrect, game over")
```

It results in incorrect if in put any number, and fizz and buzz when I just write them in. Im new to coding so I might have some things very wrong.

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}` button) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: `input()` returns a string. You need to cast numeric input to an int before you can do math with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code here assigns the input it receives from the console to a variable called 'answer'. Since the input it got from the console is a string, the 'answer' variable's type becomes a string.

```
answer = input()
```

And when you try to compare a string to and integer it will always return false. This is what is happening here.

```
if answer == x:
```

In order to fix this, you need to make sure while comparing two types for equality they are the same type. You can fix this by using `str(argument)` built-in function which takes an argument and returns it as a string. You can implement this in your code as shown below.

```
if answer == str(x):
```

There is also a lot of logic errors on your code. I've made a quick example using two variables which should be easier to understand.

```
print("Welcome to FizzBuzz.")
print("Enter a number, Fizz, Buzz or FizzBuzz:")
for currentInteger in range (1,16):
  enteredInput = input() #enteredInput is now a string.
  desiredInput = ""

  fizz = (currentInteger % 3 == 0)
  buzz = (currentInteger % 5 == 0)

  if fizz:
    desiredInput += "fizz"
  if buzz:
    desiredInput += "buzz"
  if not buzz and not fizz:
    desiredInput = str(currentInteger) #Since our desiredInput is a string we need to convert our iteration integer to a string in order to assign it to desiredInput variable.

  if desiredInput == enteredInput:
    print("Next: ")
  else:
    print("Wrong input game over.")
    break
```